# UITableView cannot select any two cells (n * 9) cells appart

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I have a multi-selection UITableView created with prototype cells from a storyboard. I am able to make multiple selections,

I am finding that if I select the cell in row 0, I am unable to select any cell a multiple of 9 rows away. i.e. 9, 18, 27, etc.

If I deselect 0, I am then able to select row 9. Doing this, however, makes rows 0, 18, 27, etc unselectable.

I have implemented the following delegate method for logging, however, when clicking these unresponsive cells, this method does not get called.

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] isSelected]) {
        NSLog(@"Already Selected");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"New Select");
    }
    return indexPath;
}
```

I have tested this on an iOS8.3 iPhone 6 Plus, an iOS9.2 iPhone 6S and an iOS9.2 iPhone 5S with the same results and the same distancing.

I don't believe it is a coincidence that there are 9 cells that fit on the screen at any one time. I assume it is connected with cell dequeuing and re-use but I've not been able to confirm that.

Does anyone have any direction on what it is that I am missing?

**EDIT:** Included `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DKIFriendTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *array;

    switch ([indexPath section]) {
        case 0:
            array = [recommendedFilteredList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            break;

        case 1:
            array = [fullFilteredList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            break;

        default:
            return nil;
            break;
    }

    BOOL selected = [selectedUsers containsObject:[array objectAtIndex:0]];

    // Due to conflicts with searching table, set whether cell is selected or not.
    if(selected)
        [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    else
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    [cell setNameText:[array objectAtIndex:1]];
    [cell setProfilePictureImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[array objectAtIndex:2]]options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:nil]]];

    return cell;
}
```

It is probably worth mentioning that the problem still occurs whether the selected boolean is checked and implemented or not. Just if it is not implemented, the search results cells do not come back as highlighted.

**EDIT:** Included `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` delegate method for further information relevant to the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}
```

**EDIT:** Addition of sample project BitBucket repository link

After disposing of the code I previously had and attempting to recreate the views from scratch, I still experienced the same problems. I then created only this section of the project again in a new, separate project where I still experienced the same problem (this time over a different separation - n * 12 instead of n * 9).

[Sample Project BitBucket link](https://bitbucket.org/treejervis/stackoverflow-931092/src)

Comment: Could it be related to scroll and having a "blocking user interaction" on the same place? I mean, if you scroll a little more, is it still unelectable?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Wherever it is in the view it remains unselectable if it is 9 (or multiple) away from one of the selected cells. As soon as the first, selected, cell is deselected, the second is now selectable.

Comment: can you please share  `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method

Comment: of course, method edited into original question.

Comment: if you have more sections than 2, cell will `return nil`. because of this your method for `willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will never be called.

Comment: I only have 2 sections and all the cells I are expecting are showing that line was only put in on the last iteration while seeing if stopping it from returning a potential null pointer exception on `[array objectAtIndex:0]`. Although there were no exceptions thrown when running the code without returning that nil value. For completeness I will include the numberOfSectionsInTableView: method in the question now.

Comment: When you say "I am finding that if I select the cell in row 0, I am unable to select any cell a multiple of 9 rows away. i.e. 9, 18, 27, etc." do you mean that nothing happens in the interface when row 9 is touched, or that some part of the code isn't behaving the way you expect? Also, do you get the same results if you remove the selection related code from the -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method?

Comment: Interface doesn't react and the delegate events are not called. I have placed breakpoints and logs inside `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, `...willDeselectRow...`, `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and `...didDeselectRow...` but none are called if a cell is already selected n*9 away. I am, however, able to select 9 in a row, with no issues and all expected delegate methods are called. Deselecting a cell allows any of the cells n*9 away from that cell to be selected.

Comment: @dave-batton I just tried removing switch and only using a single data array in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as you suggested in your edit but it made no difference to the selecting.

Comment: And you removed the -selectRowAtIndexPath:animated: and -deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated: calls? Because that may be causing the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you can post this project, or a sample project that demonstrates the problem, on GitHub. Because multiple row selection in a table view with lots of rows is working as expected for me.

Comment: Yes, I removed all association to multiple sections, including the method `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`. I also artificially shortened the list of items being passed in as a datasource to only 15 before producing the modal UITableView. Still had the same problem. Cleaning and restarting Xcode and my mac didn't provide any magic solution either so I shall re-write this section of the app tomorrow. If I am still experiencing a problem, I'll extract it into an external project that I can share.

Comment: How many rows do you see at once? 7-8?

Comment: You should use  a model object to hold your data all this [array objectAtIndex:0] [array objectAtIndex:1] business is terrible code smell. model.user, model.name, model.image :)

Comment: @PéterKovács in the actual project 9 rows are visible/partially visible. After disposing of and recreating the table and associated classes, I still have the same problem so have just created a sample project on BitBucket to share. On that project, the first 11 are visible and the unselectable rows are (n * 11) from whichever row is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i checked a project and find the problem.

```
- (void) setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    [_tickImage setHidden:!selected];
}
```

you override a method of tableviewcell however not called the super function. after doing this, all the flow in selection/deselection is acted like you wanted.

```
- (void) setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    [super setSelected:selected];
    [_tickImage setHidden:!selected];
}
```

Comment: I knew I was foolishly missing something, I just couldn't see what it was that I hadn't done! Works beautifully with your solution. Very grateful, meth. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is thinking that `[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] isSelected]` is a valid way to see if a row is selected.

If there's no visible cell for the row at `indexPath`, then `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` returns nil. In Objective-C, you can send any message to nil, and get back nil/false/0. So if the row at `indexPath` has no visible cell, your test will always return false, saying the row isn't selected.

The correct way to check whether the table view thinks a row is selected is to ask the table view which rows are selected:

```
if ([tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows containsObject:indexPath]) {
    // row is selected
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob, the only place I use isSelected is during the `-tableView: willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method to determine which log message to print, it doesn't the run any logic to adjust which indexPath is returned. In my problem, the cells are all displaying and when selected, they are still displaying as selected. However, attempting to select a row (n * 9) away from a previously selected row will not trigger any of the delegate methods. So as long as row 0 is selected, row 10 is unselectable. As soon as row 0 is deselected, row 10 becomes able to become selected.